# Javascript Noob place array into innerHTML with elements separated by newline

Tags: javascript

i am trying to place array into `innerHTML` but add a newline after each element,

```
var ingr_list = [];

//then i push some items

if (checkBox.checked == true){
    text.style.display = "none"; 
    ingr_list.push(nameofingredient);
    document.getElementById('ingredienttype').innerHTML = ingr_list;
```

As for now it just show array as entire line which ruins my responsiveness (the longer the array gets the wider screen grow which i do not know how to fix - `\n` or would do the trick)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Join the array elements with `<br>` tags like this:

```
var output = ingr_list.join('<br>');
document.getElementById('ingredienttype').innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: @jdow - You are very welcome! Please accept my answer.